# Почему происходят перебои в домашней интернет сети?

Tags: сеть, маршрутизация, mikrotik

Для начала попытаюсь обрисовать вам словами схему:

1. В квартиру приходит интернет-кабель, который подключается в MikroTik hEX RB750Gr3 (далее просто MikroTik);
2. От MikroTik идут несколько кабелей. Например, к роутеру (Keenetic Giga II) и ПК.

После покупки, распаковки и включения MikroTik максимум что было сделано - это первичная настройка с вводом IP, шлюзов и тд. Далее я подключил те кабели на выход и уже больше не возвращался к MikroTik.

На ПК и на роутере замечена одна проблема - перебои (не частые, но в день их может быть несколько). Роутер, который раздает Wi-Fi, вообще периодически может умереть из-за одного подобного перебоя (либо перестает "видеть интернет", либо просто секунд на 10-20 впадет в ступор, либо еще что-то подобное). У ПК, кстати, схожая ситуация - на нем пропадает интернет на несколько секунд (примерно на 10-20), а затем снова все нормально. Судя по всему проблема идентичная у роутера и ПК, просто ПК покрепче будет, а роутер может умереть и придется перезагружать его.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, на что это похоже? Как это можно вылечить? Я никогда с таким не сталкивался и не могу даже прикинуть, в чем может быть дело. Ситуация критическая.

Comment: @Problem196 понял. Как словлю проблему еще раз - возьму логи за этот период и выложу тут.

Comment: Хорошо, буду ждать пуш.

Comment: @Problem196 только что был сбой. Зашел в логи MikroTik - там ничего нет. Последние две строки - это May/13/2018 01:38:38 и May/13/2018 18:33:18. Самая последняя - это авторизация в веб интерфейсе. Сбой был как раз в 18:32 - 18:33. То есть в логах нет ничего...

Comment: Ищите логи в другом месте.

Comment: @Problem196 так всмысле. У меня MikroTik, да ПК, который подключен к нему. Где в другом? У ПК просто пропадает интернет. На кабеле его просто-напросто нет (несколько секунд).

Comment: Ну вот у меня тоже есть MikroTik, и ПК, но вот логи у меня почему-то есть. Не знаю почему, но что-то мне подсказывает, потому-что у меня Debian)